# Converting a price as a string to useable number in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to convert a price value obtained from a URL as a string into a number. The returned string gives the price with the dollar sign.

```
function [ price ] = price( url )
%UNTITLED4 Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here

x = urlread(url)

y = regexpi(x, '<span id="ajaxPrice" class="pReg" itemprop="price">(.*?)</span>','tokens')

price = y{1}{1}

end
```

That is the function I am using to get the value for the price.

When I use the function:

```
material = price('url')
```

It will output

```
material = '$578.56'
```

I am sure there is an easy solution, but I am having difficulty getting there. `num2str` returns an empty array. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
function [ price ] = price( url )
%UNTITLED4 Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here

x = urlread(url)

y = regexpi(x, '<span id="ajaxPrice" class="pReg" itemprop="price">(.*?)</span>','tokens')

price = y{1}{1}

end
```

Answer (score 0):

For future google-ers

```
function [ price ] = price( url )  
%UNTITLED4 Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here

x = urlread(url)

y = regexpi(x, '<span id="ajaxPrice" class="pReg" itemprop="price">(.*?\d*)</span>','tokens')

z = y{1}{1}

a = strrep(z,'$','')

price = str2num(a)

end
```